# How to set Corona notification big view

Tags: coronasdk

I can't seem to find any method to set notification arrive in big view (multi-line message in notification). Is anyone know how to set this thing up?

here is the example from native android = [Native Android Notification Big View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ApplyStyle)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you setup a local notification, if that's what you are referring to:

http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/events/appNotification/index.html#localnot

Example code:

```
local futureTime = 9 * 60  --9 minute alarm "snooze"
--OR:
local futureTime = os.date( "!*t", os.time() + (9 * 60) )

local options = {
    alert = "Wake up!",
    badge = native.getProperty( "applicationIconBadgeNumber" ) + 1,
    sound = "alarm.caf",
    custom = { msg = "Alarm" }
}

local notificationID = system.scheduleNotification( futureTime, options )
```